(Minecraft Realms) world.getTimeOfDay(); actionbar error 7 AM, 10 AM
I'm creating an addon that displays the time, date, and year in Minecraft Bedrock. It works normally in both multiplayer and single-player worlds, but when placed in Realms, the action bar text is empty between the hours of 7 AM and 10 AM. After 10 AM, the text reappears but disappears again at 7 AM, continuing in this cycle. What could be the problem?
7 AM:

10 AM:

import { world, system } from '@minecraft/server';
function formatGameTime(ticks) {
    let hours = Math.floor((ticks / 1000 + 6) % 24);
    let minutes = Math.floor((ticks % 1000) / 16.6667);
    return `${hours.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
}
function calculateDate(days) {
    const startYear = 500;
    const daysPerYear = 360;
    const daysPerMonth = 30;
    const yearsPassed = Math.floor(days / daysPerYear);
    const currentYear = startYear + yearsPassed;
    const remainingDaysAfterYears = days % daysPerYear;
    const monthsPassed = Math.floor(remainingDaysAfterYears / daysPerMonth);
    const currentMonth = monthsPassed + 1;
    const currentDay = remainingDaysAfterYears % daysPerMonth + 1;
    return { day: currentDay, month: currentMonth, year: currentYear };
}
function calculateDayOfWeek(days) {
    const daysOfWeek = ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"];
    return daysOfWeek[days % 7];
}
function updateGameTime() {
    const players = world.getAllPlayers();
    const gameTime = world.getTimeOfDay();
    const formattedTime = formatGameTime(gameTime);
    const currentDayInGame = world.getDay();
    const currentDate = calculateDate(currentDayInGame);
    const dayOfWeek = calculateDayOfWeek(currentDayInGame);
    const spacePadding = " ".repeat(20);
    const timeText = `${spacePadding}${formattedTime}${spacePadding}`;
    const dateText = `${dayOfWeek} ${currentDate.day.toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${currentDate.month.toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${currentDate.year}`;

    // Enviar mensagem de log para o chat do jogo
    players.forEach(player => {
        player.runCommand(`title @s actionbar ${timeText}\\n${dateText}`);
    });
}
system.runInterval(updateGameTime, 20);

I didn't find any documentation addressing the issue.

I am not familiar with this API, and I haven't looked at your code in detail.  However, hearing that the code behaves correctly except for some small consistent window of time each day makes me believe that this is a time zone issue.  For instance, perhaps your code is calculating in or assuming one time zone, and the user's computer or the server or something is assuming another time zone.  And in your code, this is manifesting as the data not displaying at all.  Maybe there's an exception being thrown due to that or something.

The code in the question is not Java. And why the JSON tag? Please edit your tags to fix it

@Rai I would say that since this code does not directly rely on manipulation of or coding in JSON, and no JSON code is shown, that the "json" tag shouldn't be on this question.  Someone who is an expert in or interested in JSON questions wouldn't be able to provide extra value in this question over another coder, for example.

The code seems JavaScript which is a different language than Java. Please correct the tags.

Can you check what the raw results of world.getTimeOfDay() and world.getDay() are when it's not working? Also, does it work if you only print the day, or only the time?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica has a good point.  That's a really good way to debug this: seeing whether either of those two return unexpected values or throw exceptions.  And seeing whether excluding one of those fixes the other (narrowing down the culprit to exactly one of those two).

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica
It worked when I printed only the time.

@M.Justin @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I solved the problem by combining the texts and removing the line break.     const combinedText = `${formattedTime} - ${dayOfWeek} ${currentDate.day.toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${currentDate.month.toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${currentDate.year}`;

You should post that in an answer.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Ok! thanks for your support!

I solved the problem by combining the texts and removing the line break.
const combinedText = `${formattedTime} - ${dayOfWeek} ${currentDate.day.toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${currentDate.month.toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${currentDate.year}`;

players.forEach(player => {
    player.runCommand(`title @s actionbar ${combinedText}`);
});


Were there supposed to be backticks around the code in the declaration of combinedText?

I added the backticks, since it looks like they were intended.
